# Upload files with HTTPWebrequest from SilverLight application (Why does Content Length is 13?)

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, file-upload, httpwebrequest

Friends!
Help me, please!

I try to post file from Silverlight. I use such class:

```
public class HttpHelper
    {
        public WebRequest Request { get; set; }
        public Stream Filestream { get; private set; }

        public HttpHelper(Stream filestream)
        {            
            Request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.mysite.com/recieve");                
            Request.Method = "POST";
            Request.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Filestream = filestream;
        }

        private static void BeginFilePostRequest(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            HttpHelper helper = ar.AsyncState as HttpHelper;
            if (helper != null)
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[helper.Filestream.Length];
                int sf = helper.Filestream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)helper.Filestream.Length);
                //helper.Request.ContentLength = bytes.Length; //It doesn't work in SL
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(helper.Request.EndGetRequestStream(ar)))
                {
                    writer.Write(bytes);
                }
                helper.Request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(HttpHelper.BeginResponse), helper);
            }
        }

        private static void BeginResponse(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            HttpHelper helper = ar.AsyncState as HttpHelper;
            if (helper != null)
            {
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)helper.Request.EndGetResponse(ar);
                if (response != null)
                {
                    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    if (stream != null)
                    {
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                        {
                            //anything...
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void PostFile()
        {            
            this.Request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(HttpHelper.BeginFilePostRequest), this);
        }
    }
```

I have Stream in my silverlight application and try to call PostFile by click submit button:

```
private void submit_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {           
            //...         
            HttpHelper helper = new HttpHelper(memory_stream);
            helper.PostFile();
        }
```

But mysite recieve request without file. It just has ContentLength 13. What's problem?

Comment: I'm fighting with the same problem, however in my case silverlight won't even do any request to my java web service. Have you solved it yet?

Answer (score 0):

Try Flush on your writer before exiting the `using` block, you should also call `Close` on the stream retrieved from `EndGetRequestStream`.

Comment: I also get 13. did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

you HAVE TO Flush and Dispose HTTP request stream and all downstream streams, then it works.